# What does "I assume no risk for these products myself" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In 2015 movie "The Big Short" about 2007 subprime mortgage crisis, one of the main characters Mark Baum (MB) has a meeting with CDO manager (CM) in a sushi bar.

Among other things, MB asks:

> Are you at all concerned about the rising default rates?

to which CM leans toward MB and answers in lower voice:

> I assume no risk for these products myself, Mark.

What does this last line by CM mean exactly? Is it that *I don't think there is any real problem here* or rather that *Even if there is a problem, I cannot be held responsible, so I don't care*?

For more context - [here](http://youtu.be/A25EUhZGBws?t=14s) is also a youtube clip, the part I'm quoting starts at 1:05

Comment: It's actually impossible to say without more context.  CM's statement is *deliberately ambiguous* and could mean various things, depending on the previous conversation.  It could mean that CM thinks that they are risky, or that they are **not** risky, or that CM himself is not invested in these products, or any number of other things.

Comment: This answer on [movies.se] might help with the context: https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/53026

Comment: "Assume" in this context means "To take upon oneself". For example, "I will show you how to attach the fire extinguisher to your office chair if you really want me to, but I assume no responsibility for what happens after that."

Comment: Sorry I meant to ping @Andrew about my comment on the context. That post has more of the script around that statement that would help people answer your question properly.

Comment: What @ColleenV said. I haven't looked at the full context, which would probably rule out a more "contrived" interpretation anyway, but *in principle* with no further context it would at least be feasible to suppose the speaker meant something completely different - along the lines of *When I evaluate these (financial) products, I assume ("**pretend**" to believe) that they carry no risk, which is why I'm prepared to persuade gullible old people to invest their life savings in them*. But realistically, that's not likely to be a credible interpretation in the context as given.

Comment: @xaxa  I guess my point is that I *know* what the movie is about, and understand the context of the financial meltdown of 2008 and how risky investments were sold as "AAA".  So I can *guess* what the writer *meant* when he has this character say this line (with a knowing smirk).   As FumbleFingers says, it implies that Mark knows he's doing something underhanded and deceptive, but he feels the banks know and accept the risks .  However, in a different context the line would mean something completely different.

Comment: @Andrew Pretty much everything we say can mean something different in a different context... I'm not sure I understand your point.

Comment: @ColleenV seems like you were the first to give the answer, please post it below, so that I could accept it

Comment: I will write a complete answer when I have some time to do it properly, although I hope that you aren't discounting Jay's answer just because I dashed off a quick comment while he was writing a more comprehensive answer. Being first isn't all that important because the community should be collaborating and not competing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "assume" has two very different meanings. (1) To suppose something to be true without looking for evidence. As in, "I assume that Mayor Jones will be re-elected again." "I assume that anyone who disagrees with me has not studied the subject." (2) To take on a responsibility. "As part of the buyout of XYZ Company, we are assuming their debts." "When the president was shot, the vice president assumed the duties of his office."

In this case, the speaker is using definition 2. He is saying that he will NOT assume any responsibility for the risks involved in the product under discussion. I'd have to know the context to say exactly what that means, whether he means that he is not accepting moral responsibility if others buy them and then they lose money, or that he has managed to avoid legal responsibility, or what.